# Django project show processed data instantly

Tags: python, django

I have one django project. It has one function in view.py to process the data from the inputs to give the output for other function. However the processing time for the function is kind of long. I want to fulfill the instant demonstration of the processed output. How could I achieved that? The following processing() function is for the processing purpose. And the output 'user_entries' is for the demonstration in results() as followed.

```
def processing(request):
    import sys
    n = []
    for topic in Topic.objects.filter(owner=request.user).order_by("date_added"):
        entries = topic.entries.all()
        m = []
        for p in entries:
            q = p.text
            m.append(q)
        n.append(m)
    list = []
    start(list, n)
    request.session['user_entries'] = list
    return request.session['user_entries']

def results(request):
    data = processing(request)
    return render(request, "project/results.html", {"datas": data})
```

In the start() function of the processing() function. There is one part list.append() to add new output into list. But it seems that the new appended list cannot be transferred and show the instant results in project/results.html?

Comment: list is a reserved keyword, you can't use it as a variable name.

Comment: also no need to pass an empty list to start function. Pass it just one argument `n`. Create an empty list inside start function, append stuff to it, then return that list. In your view function you should then do something like `myList = start(n)`. Right now what you are trying to do will not work, there is concept of scope for variables.

Comment: Minor correction: You _can_ use reserved words as variable names -- Python will allow it -- but you definitely shouldn't. Also, this question really needs clarification; it's not clear what the goal is, e.g. whether those nested lists should be one flat list, what the template looks like, what exactly `start()` is adding, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing could likely be done a lot more simply.

```
def results(request):
    return render(
        request, 
        "project/results.html", 
        {
            "user_entries": Entry.objects.filter(topic__owner=request.user),
            "start_values": "...", # Whatever start is appending...
        },
    )
```

Since you have a foreign key from entry to User, you could also use `request.user.topic_set.all()` to get the current user's topics.

Or, if you actually do need those lists nested...

```
            # ...
            "user_entries": (
                topic.entries.all() for topic in
                Topic.objects.filter(owner=request.user)
            ),
            # ...
```

Just based on what you're showing us, it seems like your ordering -- for both Topic and Entry -- should probably have a sensible default set in, e.g., `Topic.Meta.ordering`, which in this case would probably look like this:

```
class Topic(models.Model):
    # ...
    class Meta:
        ordering = ("date_added",)
    # ...
```

That way, in this and most other cases, you would not have to apply `.ordering(...)` manually.

Comment: This looks more efficient!